# keyframe multiple objects rigid body

Tags: animation, keyframes, rigid-body-simulation

Can I animate rigid bodies using keyframes to enable and disable the "dynamic" checkbox, and if so, is it possible with multiple selected objects?

My project is a ball that collides with a wall, but first *encapsulates* it with a wall, creating breakage and cracks, after the total collapse.

what I tried:

- after cell fracture calculation, I selected the various pieces, all together
- then, I first tried to give the rigid ACTIVE body,
- then in the left panel, section " PHYSICS ", I clicked on" COPY FROM ACTIVE ",
- then in the right panel, in the" rigid body "section, right click the mouse, click the "dynamic" check and
- then" insert keyframe ",
- then right click again on "dynamic" and clicked "copy to selected",

and so on the various frames, to turn it on and off, but the problem is that during keyframing, when I start from the first frame and i press PLAY, some pieces follow keyframe, the rest falls following physics

why is this happening? how can I fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your process, but it sounds like you're doing some things that should not be necessary. What is the end result you want to achieve? Maybe there's an easier way.

Comment: then, I have a plan and a sphere. the sphere strikes the wall and clings, creating small breaks, then cracks, and then collapses, all at different times. I do not know if I explained it well

Comment: I'm not sure that animate, with keyframes, settings like "dynamic" is a good idea... even if it's possible. That setting provides a specific simulation behaviour to the involved object, that will be also evaluated together with all others... forcing it to change it during the simulation may easily give unexpected results, imho...

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want the sphere object to fracture in iterative steps, breaking apart once, with some chunks then breaking again into even smaller pieces?